# Flutter Signalr Listener is not connected in 2nd screen after migrated to null safety stable version

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr, flutter-dependencies, bloc

Chatting was working perfectly before migrating to null safety using signalr. But after migrating It is not working in chatting part.

Scenario is like there are 2 screens where I am using signalr.
1)Chatlist.
2)Chatting with person.

listener in Chatlist is perfect but in 2nd screen it is not working(Just worked when I installed and run for the 1st time). Weird issue.

All was working in old. I am using bloc for statemanagement and also migrated to yield to emit.

Piece of code is like:

```
 void listenOnMessageReceived(
      HubConnection hubConnection,
      Function(Message? chatMessageReceive) onMessageReceived,
      ) {
    final SocketResponseCallBack chatMessageReceived =
        (response) => onMessageReceived(Message.fromJson(response));
    final hubMethod = HubMethod(
        CHAT_RECEIVED_MESSAGE_METHOD_NAME,
        SignalRHelper.toSocketFunction(
            CHAT_RECEIVED_MESSAGE_METHOD_NAME, chatMessageReceived));

    bool exists = listenOnHubMethod.any((method) => method.methodName == CHAT_RECEIVED_MESSAGE_METHOD_NAME);
    if(exists) {
      listenOnHubMethod.removeWhere((element) =>
      element.methodName == CHAT_RECEIVED_MESSAGE_METHOD_NAME);
      SignalRHelper(hubConnection: hubConnection).on(
        hubMethod.methodName,
        hubMethod.methodFunction,
      );
      listenOnHubMethod.add(hubMethod);
    }else{
      SignalRHelper(hubConnection: hubConnection).on(
        hubMethod.methodName,
        hubMethod.methodFunction,
      );
      listenOnHubMethod.add(hubMethod);
    }
  }
```

I am having 2 types of above code in different screens. but it is working in only 1 screen and not listening in 2nd screen.

here is a piece of signalr listener code:

```
  static MethodInvocationFunc toSocketFunction(
      String methodName, SocketResponseCallBack responseCallBack) {
    return (arguments) {
      try {
        if (arguments!.isEmpty) {
          throw SocketEmptyResponseException(methodName);
        }
        final response = arguments.first;
        responseCallBack(response);
      } on FormatException {
        throw SocketResponseException(methodName);
      }
    };
  }
```

Is there any limitations in migration of stable version or anything else. Every help is appreciable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use signalR, on IOS it will be impossible to run listener on background or when app is closed and you will miss messages. Use FCM.

Comment: Yeah thats true and thanks for suggestion but that issue was resolved by firebase notification. So it will not be issue.